# Laravel mail - multiple variables

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to pass multiple variables to a mailable in Laravel but only the `$request` seems to be passed to the view.

In my controller function:

```
 Mail::to( $request->opponent_email )->send( new ChallengeOpponent($request, $challenge) );
```

in ChallengeOpponent.php

```
 /**
   * The instance.
   *
   * @var Order
   */
  public $request, $challenge;

  /**
   * Create a new message instance.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function __construct(Request $request, $challenge)
  {
       $this->request      = $request;
       $this->challenge    = $challenge;
  }

  /**
   * Build the message.
   *
   * @return $this
   */
  public function build()
  {
      return $this->from('noresponse@fullscale.com')
              ->view('emails.challenge-opponent');
  }
```

Can you only pass one variable? I know there is information in `$challegne` in my controller so that isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass any parameter to class and to pass to view you can do somethink like this

```
 public function build()
      {
          return $this->from('noresponse@fullscale.com')
                  ->view('emails.challenge-opponent',['requestDetail'=> $this->request,'challenge'=>$this->challenge]);
      }
```

Comment: I assume you meant `'request'=> $this->request,'challenge'=>$this->challenge` but that still didnt work.

Comment: can you print challenge and reuquest  in constructor and check you are gettign value or not.

Comment: Sorry, there was an issue in the view so it now works. I would just change in your answer `'challenge'=>$request->challenge` to `'challenge'=>$this->challenge`